# How can I extract values from a custom flat file header into variables?

Tags: etl, ssis

I have been stuck for a while with this problem and I have no clue. I am trying to upload multiple CSV files which has dates but I wanted the dates stored as date variables so I use the date variables to form part of the column in a table using script componet and I have no idea how to create the dates as date variables in SSIS.

CSV files look as shown below when opened in Excel.

#### CSV data 1:

```
Relative Date: 02/01/2013
Run Date: 15/01/2013

Organisation,AreaCode,ACount
Chadwell,RM6,50
Primrose,RM6,60
```

#### CSV data 2:

```
Relative Date: 14/02/2013
Run Date: 17/02/2013

Organisation,AreaCode,ACount
Second Ave,E12,110
Fourth Avenue, E12,130
```

I want the *`Relative Date`* and *`Run Date`* stored as date variables. I hope I made sense.

Answer (score 2):

Your best solution would be to use a **Script Task** in your control flow. With this you would pre-process your CSV files - you can easily parse the first two rows, retrieving your wanted dates and storing them into two variables created beforehand. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135941.aspx)

Important to make sure when passing the variables into the script task you set them as **ReadWriteVariables**. Use these variables in any way you desire afterwards.

---

**Updated Quick Walkthrough:**

I presume that the CSV files you will want to import will be located in the same directory:

[image: CSV files]

Add a **Foreach Loop Container** which will loop through the files in your specified directory and inside, a **Script Task** which will be responsible for parsing the two dates in each of your files and a **Data Flow Task** which you will use for your file import.

[image: ForEach Loop Container]

Create the variables you will be using - one for the FileName/Path, two for the two dates you want to retrieve. These you won't fill in as it will be done automatically in your process.

[image: Package variables]

Set-up your **Foreach Loop Container**:

1. Select a Foreach File Enumerator
2. Select a directory folder that will contain your files. (Even better, add a variable that will take in a path you specify. This can then be read into the enumerator using its expression builder)
3. Wildcard for the files that will be searched in that directory.

[image: Foreach Loop settings]

You also need to map each filename the enumerator generates to the variable you created earlier.

[image: Variable mapping]

Open up your **Script Task**, add the three variables to the **ReadWriteVariables** section. This is important, otherwise you won't be able to write to your variables.

This is the script I used for the purpose. Not necessarily the best, works for this example.

```cs
public void Main()
{
  string filePath = this.Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString();
  using (StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath))
  {
    string line = "";
    bool getNext = true;

    while (getNext && (line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
      if(line.Contains("Relative Date"))
      {
        string date = getDate(line);
        this.Dts.Variables["User::RelativeDate"].Value = date;

        // Test Event Information
        bool fireAgain = false;
        this.Dts.Events.FireInformation(1, "Rel Date", date,
                                        "", 0, ref fireAgain);
      }
      else if (line.Contains("Run Date"))
      {
        string date = getDate(line);
        this.Dts.Variables["User::RunDate"].Value = date;

        // Test Event Information
        bool fireAgain = false;
        this.Dts.Events.FireInformation(1, "Run Date", date,
                                        "", 0, ref fireAgain);

        break;
      }
    }
  }
  Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}

private string getDate(string line)
{
  Regex r = new Regex(@"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}");
  MatchCollection matches = r.Matches(line);
  return matches[matches.Count - 1].Value;
}
```

The results from the execution of the **Script Task** for the two CSV files. The dates can now be used in any way you fancy in your **Data Flow Task**. Make sure you skip the first rows you don't need to import in your **Source** configuration.

[image: Execution Results]

Comment: Milen could you guide me a bit further as I am not sure how I can parse the first two rows using Script Task as I am not familiar with Script Task. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: There you go, hope it helps!